# Github not loading css file when deployed by github pages

Tags: html, css, github, deployment

I was working on a preview card component and when I uploaded my code to a repo to deploy it, github doesn't seem to load my css file style.

note: not my first time to deploy on github pages.
thanks in advance!

repo link: https://github.com/HanyAyad/Stats-preview-card-component-

live-website link on github pages: https://hanyayad.github.io/Stats-preview-card-component-/

same website deployed on netlify (working fine): https://62116b02da6915993f04d79c--suspicious-hypatia-156ece.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because the folder is CSS/styles.css and your declaration in index.html is css/styles.css?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested here and when importing your CSS file, you are using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

when you should be using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css" >
```

Answer (score 0):

URLs may be case-sensitive, it depends on what file system you are running your website.

Try renaming the folder `CSS` to `css`.

Answer (score -1):

The directory in your repo is named `CSS` and not `css` as expected. So, please rename the directory.

It only works on Netlify because it doesn't take casing into account, for some reason. (That is, `https://62116b02da6915993f04d79c--suspicious-hypatia-156ece.netlify.app/CsS/sTyLe.css` works fine.)